White screen on BottomSheet when keyboard is displayed
I'm working on an app and I'm having this issue on Samsung devices. Any idea how to fix this?


I am using the standard com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText and com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout for this component and it works perfectly on my devices but I have this problem with Samsung devices
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/descriptionTextLayout"
    style="@style/text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/descriptions"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/datesRangeTextLayout">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
        style="@style/dropdown_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/write_notes_here"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        tools:text="some test text..." />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


The problem was with the height of the bottom sheet layout, I changed the overall height of the elements with the keyboard so that they fit on the screen and now everything works fine
